# Batch convert Flash to HTML5 canvas project and publish, jsfl

Tags: html, flash, adobe, jsfl

I want to batch convert Flash projects to CreateJS projects and publish them.

I've converted some Flash projects to HTML5 canvas projects, but I have a lot to convert and it is tedious.  When publishing, the MP3s generated are invalid and don't play.  The WAV files in question play fine in the IDE.  So additionally, I will have to export sounds separately

How would I write the jsfl to batch run the built-in html5 conversion jsfl script (accessible in the "Commands" menu) and to batch publish?

I'm not sure how to use this: [Can we export from flash to createjs from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622499/can-we-export-from-flash-to-createjs-from-the-command-line)

I've slightly modified the sound export script to recursively create folders:
[Is it possible to use jsfl to export sound files from flash library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909053/is-it-possible-to-use-jsfl-to-export-sound-files-from-flash-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a jsfl script to batch convert, publish and extract sounds: https://gist.github.com/jhiswin/58928a237f8a7ebd2f69